# NestJS and Handlebars are not showing images

Tags: handlebars.js, nestjs

I am trying to use images in my handlebars templates which are used for emails. The only problem is that the images are not showing. I have tried several ways to solve the problem, but nothing helped.

`main.ts` configs:

```
app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'static'))
app.setBaseViewsDir(join(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'static', 'templates'))
app.setViewEngine('hbs')
```

Folder structure:

```
-src
--static
---img
----image1.png
----image2.png
---templates
----email1.hbs
----email2.hbs
```

How image would be used in the template:

```
<img src="/static/img/logo.png" alt="logo">
```

In email it looks like this:

```
https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/IhSgHQ3zXQ7Wh6MMxDAzkCjjFuvjZF3OI_Ru5CEQg3dGnin7xXJdUfjVTIg8Ag=s0-d-e1-ft#http:///static/img/logo.png
```

Comment: Judging by the `http:///static/img/logo.png` at the end of your output source string, you will need to include the hostname in your URL, as in `www.example.com/static/img/logo.png`.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [Nest.js official documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mvc), first install hbs module and then set the App module according to the code below and access your static files as in the second part of the code below.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
import { join } from 'path';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'static'),
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Using static files in your templates:**

```
<div>
    <img src='/img/image1.png' alt='' />
</div>
```

Take out the static directory from the src directory and **place it next to it**:

```
-src
-static
--img
---image1.png
---image2.png
--templates
---email1.hbs
---email2.hbs
```